# Selenium InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

- Gecko Driver Version: 0.20
- Platform: Windows
- Firefox: Nightly 61.0a1 and 60
- Selenium: 3.8.1

When I try to send the sendkeys command to upload a file I get this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: C:/file.abc

On chrome it works great, I've seen that this problem has been found by other users in the old versions of firefox and that it has been fixed, but to me the problem persists.

This is the code:

```
site = "https://www.sendspace.com/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(site)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys('C:/file.abc')
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is `'C:/file.abc'`, but not `'C:\\file.abc'`?

Comment: @Andersson I try too but i get the same error.

Comment: @Andersson Oooooh, I tried to put the path so in the old version of firefox, where there was still the bug, I have not tried in the new version of firefox, it works!